# Algorithm or code to print the binary tree of agents

Tags: java, agents-jade

I try to write code in jade (Java Agent DEvelopment Framework) to print the binary tree of agents in sma. I want to print tree inorder traversal with origin algorithm:

1. Traverse the left subtree, i.e., call Inorder(left-subtree)
2. Visit the root.
3. Traverse the right subtree, i.e., call Inorder(right-subtree)

And my node agent is:

```
class Noeud {
    private Integer value = null;
    private AID gauche = null;
    private AID droit = null;
    private AID pere = null;
}
```

In my agent to print, I use `CyclicBehaviour` as extensions. With my code:

```
public class ReceiveAffichageBehaviour extends CyclicBehaviour{     
@Override
public void action() {
    MessValueGauche();
    MessValue();
    MessValueDroit();
}

private void MessValueGauche() {
    MessageTemplate messageTemplate = MessageTemplate.and(
            MessageTemplate.MatchOntology(Constants.AFFICHAGE_VALUE_GAUCHE),
            MessageTemplate.MatchPerformative(ACLMessage.REQUEST)
    );
    ACLMessage receiveMsg = myAgent.receive(messageTemplate);
    if (receiveMsg != null) {
        String contenu = receiveMsg.getContent() + "(";
        ACLMessage message = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);

        if (noeud.getGauche() == null) {
            message.setOntology(Constants.AFFICHAGE_VALUE);
            message.addReceiver(myAgent.getAID());
        } else {
            message.setOntology(Constants.AFFICHAGE_VALUE_GAUCHE);
            message.addReceiver(noeud.getGauche());
        }

        message.setContent(contenu);
        myAgent.send(message);

    } else {
        block();
    }
}

private void MessValue() {
    MessageTemplate messageTemplate = MessageTemplate.and(
            MessageTemplate.MatchOntology(Constants.AFFICHAGE_VALUE),
            MessageTemplate.MatchPerformative(ACLMessage.REQUEST)
    );
    ACLMessage receiveMsg = myAgent.receive(messageTemplate);
    if (receiveMsg != null) {
        String contenu = receiveMsg.getContent() + (noeud.getValue() == null ? "" : noeud.getValue().toString());
        ACLMessage message = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);

        if (noeud.getDroit() == null){
            message.setOntology(Constants.AFFICHAGE_VALUE_DROIT);
            message.addReceiver(myAgent.getAID());
        } else if (noeud.getDroit().equals(receiveMsg.getSender())){
            message.setOntology(Constants.AFFICHAGE_VALUE_DROIT);
            message.addReceiver(noeud.getPere());
        } else {
            message.setOntology(Constants.AFFICHAGE_VALUE_GAUCHE);
            message.addReceiver(noeud.getDroit());
        }
        message.setContent(contenu);
        myAgent.send(message);

    } else {
        block();
    }
}

private void MessValueDroit() {
    MessageTemplate messageTemplate = MessageTemplate.and(
            MessageTemplate.MatchOntology(Constants.AFFICHAGE_VALUE_DROIT),
            MessageTemplate.MatchPerformative(ACLMessage.REQUEST)
    );
    ACLMessage receiveMsg = myAgent.receive(messageTemplate);
    if (receiveMsg != null) {
        String contenu = receiveMsg.getContent() + ")";
        ACLMessage message = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
        message.setContent(contenu);

        if (noeud.getDroit() == null && noeud.getGauche() == null ){
            if (noeud.getPere().equals(Constants.AID_RACINE)){
                message.setPerformative(ACLMessage.CONFIRM);
            } else {
                message.setOntology(Constants.AFFICHAGE_VALUE_GAUCHE);
            }
            message.addReceiver(noeud.getPere());
        }

        myAgent.send(message);

    } else {
        block();
    }
}
```

I don't know to fix the infini loop in my code. Who can help me the detailed algorithm instead the general? Or could fix my bug in code? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A cyclicBehaviour is infinite by nature. Do not use a cyclic if you want the behaviour to stop.
Just use a simpleBehaviour and set the finished boolean at true when you want to remove it from the agent.